# Symfony 3.3.6 change to service auto loading from 3.2

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2, symfony-3.3

I updated to 3.3.6 yesterday and in setting up a new service I have created in AppBundle. Old style of service registration works - when I try the new approach it is not.

I have a service

**AppBundle/Service/SomeService.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class SomeService {

}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    # THIS WORKS
    #app.some_service:
    #    class: AppBundle\Service\SomeService
    #    arguments: []

    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false      

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
```

Inside my action I try and use the service:

```
   $someService = $this->get(SomeService::class);

   // THIS WORKS
   //$someService = $this->get('app.some_service');
```

I get the following error:

> You have requested a non-existent service
>   "AppBundle\Service\SomeService".

What am I missing or not understanding about the changes made to 3.3?

I feel it's likely something I missed due to upgrading from 3.2 to 3.3+

Ideas?

Comment: Need to set public: true as a minimum in order to access a service via get

Comment: I tried that but it seems to have caused issues with a menu service I registered:

```
Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Event\ConfigureMenuEvent": argument "$menu" of method "__construct()" references interface "Knp\Menu\ItemInterface" but no such service exists. It cannot be auto-registered because it is from a different root namespace.
```

Comment: OK so I excluded the menu from being registered  -- that did the trick so it seems - thank you :)

Comment: This might help with the interface issue though (imho) it somewhat defeats the purpose of autowiring: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces